# ReportViewer control (v10) and height

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, reportingservices-2005

We used to have SSRS 2005 and were using ReportViewer v9 in our asp.net environment. In order to implement the height of the control correctly (100%) I went through a whole bunch of resizing javascript functions and other hacks. My understanding was that the v9 of the control could not render the height as 100% because of the IFRAME it was using. 
  Right now we upgraded to SSRS 2008 and I am implementing ReportViewer v10 control. Unfortunately, even though this version does not use the IFRAME anymore it seems like the height issue is still here. 
  Has anyone implemented the asp.net ReportViewer v10 control with width=100%, height=100% and  AsyncRendering=true correctly? I want to get rid of all the extra javascript/hacks from previous version, but I am not sure I can, since it seems like the height issue is still there.
  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update,
  Yes the ReportViewer version 10, still has the issue with the Height being all screwed up if there are other controls on the page. In case anyone else has this issue, here are my scripts to get the height of the control to work and resize correctly:
  rv1 is my report viewer control and fl is our custom parameter panel for the report parameters.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() { $find('rv1').add_propertyChanged(viewerPropertyChanged); });
$(window).resize(resize);

function viewerPropertyChanged(sender, e) {
    if (e.get_propertyName() === 'isLoading') {
        var viewer = $find('rv1');
        if (!viewer.get_isLoading())
            resizeWithOffset();        
    }
}

function resizeWithOffset() {
    resize(11);
}

function resize(offset) {
    if (typeof (offset) == 'object' || offset == 'undefined')
        offset = 0;

    // only apply if filter parameter panel is present
    var parameterHeight = $('#fl').height();
    if (parameterHeight != null) {

        // get height of the report viewer toolbar
        var toolbarHeight = $('#rv1_fixedTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(4)').height();

        // get height of the padding between actual report content and toolbar
        var paddingHeight = $('#rv1_fixedTable').height() - ($('#rv1_fixedTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3)').height() + toolbarHeight);

        // set new height.        
        var newHeight = ($(window).height() - (parameterHeight + toolbarHeight + 11)) + offset;
        $('#rv1_fixedTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3)').height(newHeight);
        $('#rv1_fixedTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3) > div').height(newHeight);
    }
}
```